# Uploading is not working in selenium using Robot in Chrome Broswer

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

I am using the `Robot` class to upload a file but it's not working.

File explorer is appearing for uploading but the `Robot` class is not working:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("photo")).click;
Thread.sleep(2000);

StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Bug\\ui_1.png");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);  
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

### robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

How ever `Robot` is working fine using chrome browser. Facing issue with Firefox. Is there any solution available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually avoid using `Robot` and solve it with selenium only. Just send keys to the file input and then submit the form:

```
WebElement photo = driver.findElement(By.id("photo"));
photo.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Bug\\ui_1.png");

// TODO: fill out other fields

// this would find the corresponding form and submit it
photo.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for few seconds before hitting enter. Add `robot.delay(3000);` in your code as follows. This might solve the problem.

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

    robot.delay(3000);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```